# php take users input write to file, and echo out the file for user to view

Tags: php

How do I set this up such that when a user enters his first name and last name, I write it to a .html file and then give the user a link to view the information that they have just entered?

I know I could just echo that out like I am already doing with $_POST['userfName'] after Welcome, but I just want to write to some .html file and echo this information back to the user to view(see).

```
{ 
        $_SESSION['userEmail'] = $_POST['userEmail']; 
        $_SESSION['start'] = time(); 
        echo "Welcome, " . $_POST['userfName'] .  $_POST['userlName'] .". A new session has been activated for you. Click <a href="sometextfile.html">here</a> to see your information.";
        echo "<br>Your session id is: ".session_id(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this.

```
 $message = ...;
 file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."\message.html", $message);
 echo "<a href=message.html>Your message</a>
```

BUT your web server might now have permissions to write to the web directory. And it opens you up for all kind of badness. Imagine if a user wrote a php script in the message (`<? echo phpinfo()?>` for example) . now your server is compromised. You need to validate and clean your input if you do this.

**EDit**
Nick is right, using the method i suggested will cause your users to overwrite each others messages. I wouldn't recomend doing this. Follow Nicks suggestion of sending the user to a dynamically generated page.

Answer (score 2):

You want to actually generate a new HTML file for each user that logs in? That kind of defies the point of server-side scripting.

In fact, it's a bad idea security-wise to let your scripts have write access to your web server root.

What you'd want to do is link to "sometextfile.php?sessid=" or use a cookie containing their session ID, then generate that page dynamically.

If you just want to write a text file to disk somewhere, you can create a string then use file_put_contents (http://php.net/file_put_contents). This could be put in the web root, but I'm guessing that's not actually what you're trying to do.

Comment: The session is propagated automatically in a cookie in php. but otherwise good answer. +1

Comment: sometextfile.php?sessid=, Could you please elaborate on this secure idea, thank you.

Comment: Never mind, I just figured out what you were talking about, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're stumbling into the need for a **database**! Congratulations!

Since you're using PHP, the easiest/cheapest route is to either [install](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/installing-php-and-mysql.aspx) or get access to a [MySQL server](http://www.mysql.com/).

Then you can create a table storing your user's names, and give them a URL to access a dynamic page with their information on it, and you're on you're way to a promising career. For help with the MySQL, check out [this tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/).

Eventually you'll probably want to jump into a framework like [Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) (to name a few) to start doing all this dirty work for you so you can concentrate on the fancy stuff.